Issue with "InputValue" on Google home script editor YAML
Greeting all,
I'm recently playing with Google Home Script Editor, and I wanted to use the "Input" structure so I can avoid repeating my devices name.
Yet I have this error, I've checked the whole documentation and I'm clueless about this error.
The error : Field [inputValue] is unexpected in the struct. on the line inputValue:, line 9 of this script.
The script :
metadata:
  name: Roller shutter
  description: Automation of the roller shutter

#############
# INPUT
#############

inputValue:
  rollerShutters: Test device
input:
  rollerShutters:
    metadata:
      name:
        en: rollerShutters
      description:
        en: List of all roller shutters
    selector:
      type: device
      multiSelect: true

#############
# ACTIONS
#############
automations:
  #############
  # On sun rise open
  #############
  - starters:
      - type: time.schedule
        at: sunrise

    actions:
      - type: device.command.OpenClose
        openPercent: 100
        devices: $rollerShutters

  #############
  # At night close all
  #############
  - starters:
      - type: time.schedule
        at: sunset

    actions:
      - type: device.command.OpenClose
        openPercent: 0
        devices: $rollerShutters

The script is working smoothly without the input section.
Does anyone already encoutered this issue ?

After few days, the documentation return 404, and all mentions of it is removed from the documentation.
I believe it's not a feature any more

We also observed a very similar stuff at our end. I would recommend opening up a bug in this regard on the public issue tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/). Also, please provide the working script what you mentioned above is working without the input section.
